# MouseEvent.RIGHT_MOUSE_DOWN ("rightMouseDown") doesn't work in Flex4.6 Web (runs in FlashPlayer)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4.6

When I add event listener to stage in Flash Professional CS6:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.RIGHT_MOUSE_DOWN, rightMouseHandler);
```

or without constant:

```
stage.addEventListener("rightMouseDown", rightMouseHandler);
```

right mouse button work **ok**. I tested this in Flash Player 11.7 (flashplayer_11_sa_debug.exe), Firefox, Chrome, Internet Explorer.

---

But when I write this in Fash Builder 4.6 - Flex 4.6 application type Web:

```
stage.addEventListener("rightMouseDown", rightMouseHandler);
```

right mouse button **not** working.

.

**Remerks**

The same Flex project run as AIR application type makes right mouse button work properly.

---

Any ideas as to why not working in Flash Player?

^^^Edit:^^^  How I adding listener:

*Flash Builder 4.6:*

```
<s:Application applicationComplete="completeHandler()" ...> 
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function completeHandler(): void {
                stage.addEventListener("rightMouseDown", rightMouseHandler);
            }
            public function rightMouseHandler(e :MouseEvent) :void {
                var col :String = '#' + uint(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF).toString(16);
                setStyle('backgroundColor', col);
                trace(col);
            }
```

*Flash Professional CS6 in 1 frame:*

```
stage.addEventListener("rightMouseDown", rightMouseHandler);

function rightMouseHandler(e :MouseEvent) :void{
    var col :uint = uint(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF);
    stage.color = col;
    trace('#' + col.toString(16));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Flash Builder compiler options, add a higher swf version:

```
-swf-version=15
```

Comment: List of versions http://sleepydesign.blogspot.com/2012/04/flash-swf-version-meaning.html

Answer (score 0):

Is the event fired when listening on application (this on the main.mxml) ?

```
this.addEventListener("rightMouseDown", rightMouseHandler);
```

Comment: main.mxml is a child of stage, but wait...
the same problem - work in AIR, but not in Flash Player